# How to divide an object with Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode

i am trying to divide an object:

in Edit Mode, i select "Loop Cut". But the selection is only possible in that way that it divides the object in half. I didn´t found a solution to change the selection. If i wont another selection, i have to repeat that step.

But that is ok, i can live with that.

My question is, when i selected the region with the "Loop Cut", how can i process the cut? Found no possibility. The region where it would cut is shown but i can´t execute it. (I know, this is a rudimentary question...)

Comment: Can you add some images for what you want to do, images are better way to explain your question

Comment: I want to cut an object into two pieces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am showing you on a cube.
If you are loop cutting from exact center, that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and Right Clicking mouse button to exit sliding.
In `Edit Mode`:
Go to face select mode.
[image]
and select the faces on the other half.
[image]
Now press <kbd>P</kbd> and seperate by `Selection`.
[image]
Go to `Object Mode`(by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>)and select any half of cube and Press <kbd>G</kbd> to Grab and move.
[image]

> This same method works on Blender 2.79 too.

Now cube is divided into two different parts! Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you Yash. I knew, it is something very simple (and i already did it several times before) but i swear, i didn´t found the answer to simply press "P" to divide the pieces....

Comment: It was grateful for me to help, all the best!